# Как написать разные заголовки в одной строке html

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно сделать что-то на подобии этого[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот что,я сделал,я не знаю как писать новый текст по центру**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body
{
 font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;

}
.border{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
 
}

strong{
 font-size: 50px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 150%; /* Размер шрифта */
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey; /* Параметры линии под текстом */
    font-weight: normal; /* Убираем жирное начертание */
    padding-bottom: 5px; /* Расстояние от текста до линии */
   left:10%;
            width:10%;

   }
   .graficlogo{
 
 height: 5%;
 width: 5%;
 
 justify-content: left;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<head> 

 <title>Заголовок документа</title> 

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/HTML; charset=utf-8" />
  </head> 
<body>     
 <h1 align="center">Резюме</h1>
 <h1 align="center" class ="border">ФИО</h1>
 <h2 class="leftstr">Инфо</h2>

<div class="topnav">
 <li>Birthday: 2001-05-05</li>
     <li>Phone: 380630</li>
     <li>Email: yuranov8@gmail.com</li>
    </li>
    </div>
    <h2>Навики</h2>
    <div class="topnav">
     <ol>
         <li>English </li>
         <img class="graficlogo" src="img/English1.png" alt="Logo">
     <li>use PC</li>
     <img class="graficlogo" src="img/pc.png" alt="Logo">
     <li>Photoshop</li>
     <img class="graficlogo" src="img/photo.png" alt="Logo">
     <li>C++</li>
     <img class="graficlogo" src="img/C++.png" alt="Logo">
     <li>Microsoft Ofiice</li>
     <img class="graficlogo" src="img/pc.png" alt="Logo">
     <li>MySQL</li>
     <img class="graficlogo" src="img/photo.png" alt="Logo">
     <li>HTML</li>
     <img class="graficlogo" src="img/C++.png" alt="Logo">
    </ol>
    </div>

    
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Вы знакомы с flexbox или float?  Вам нужно туда копать для позиционирования объектов рядом.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0ж
}

.card {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.card-content,
.card-assets {
  padding: 80px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center
}

.card-assets {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.accent {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem
}

.text{
  margin-bottom: 1rem
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-title">Фамилия Имя</div>
  <div class="card-assets">
    <div class="accent">навыки:</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="accent">навыки:</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="accent">навыки:</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="accent">навыки:</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="accent">Описание:</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta, odit.</div>
    <div class="accent">навыки:</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta, odit.</div>
    <div class="accent">навыки:</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta, odit.</div>
    <div class="accent">навыки:</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta, odit.</div>
    <div class="accent">навыки:</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta, odit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Semenov А скажите где вы указываете длинну линии под заголовком?

Comment: Это просто нижняя рамка (`border-bottom`)